# Is it a MacOS normal behavior to switch between desktops slower while in Mission Control mode?

Tags: macos, mojave

I'm having an issue regard MacOS (Mojave 10.14.6) for some time now:

If I'm **not in** [Mission Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) mode I can instantly change between the desktops using the keyboard (`ctrl+direction`, left or right).

However if I'm **in** [Mission Control](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100) mode and try to change desktops with the same approach I have a delay of like 1 or 2 seconds.

Someone else having the same issue? There's some type of fix for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a performance issue than anything else.

Bringing up Mission Control is already a pretty complex split-second animation for your Mac to handle, especially if you have several windows open in your current desktop.

And if you have multiple desktops with several windows open, it has to render all the windows, grouped by application per desktop, and give them a different effect than usual (drop shadows are applied on the window group rather than individual windows in Mission Control) and so on.

Basically, it's a more complex task for your Mac to do, and since you're on Mojave, system UI is largely Metal, so if you have an nVidia chip or older intel graphics with no Metal 2 support, unfortunately it will feel like molasses.

The only solution would be to upgrade your hardware, or turn off the special effects by going to System Preferences -> Accessibility -> Display then checking reduce motion, reduce transparency, either one or both, depending on what you are willing to give up and how much of an improvement checking the options yield.

Comment: Reduce motion and reduce transparency didn't worked at all. I suspect from being a performance problem, just wasn't entirely sure. Anyway, to those interested my configuration is:
2,2 GHz Intel Core i7, 
16 GB 2400 MHz DDR4, 
Radeon Pro 555X 4 GB, 
Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB

Comment: Hmm... That machine really shouldn't be struggling too much with it. About how many windows do you have open on each desktop, and how many desktops do you have? Are you running any graphics intensive apps or is the laptop running hot? If you're running something like maya on one desktop and houdini on another then it'd be a lot of pressure obviously. And if your MBP is running too hot, it will limit the power draw on CPU and GPU so your system doesn't melt itself down, limiting performance.